# mongoose populate returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

## What I want to do

---

I am building a trip booking website for a transportation company.
I am trying to show the name of the person who made the booking on one of the pages.
I have a user model and a booking model.

## The User model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const UserSchema = new Schema({

  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  firstName:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  gender: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["male", "female"]
    }
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

## The Booking model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BookingSchema = new Schema({
  tripDate: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  pickupTime: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  pickupStreet: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  pickupCity: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  pickupState: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  pickupZip: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  dropOffStreet: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  dropOffCity: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  dropOffState: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  dropOffZip: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },

  booker: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
  }

}, {
  timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Booking", BookingSchema);
```

## the route

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const catchAsync = require("../utilities/catchAsync");
const ExpressError = require("../utilities/expressError");
const Booking = require("../models/booking");
const Joi = require("joi");
const {isLoggedIn} = require("../middleware/index");
const User = require("../models/user");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

router.get("/booking/:id", catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const booking = await Booking.findById(req.params.id).populate("booker");
  console.log(booking);
  if (!booking) {
        req.flash("error", "Cannot find that booking");
        return res.redirect("/booking");
    }
  res.render("booking/show", {booking});
}));
```

---

So when i console log "booking" after I populate, no information is showing up form the user
model on the log.

Comment: What happen if you don't use populate? Is your `booking`  still undefined?

Comment: What type is the booker field from you Booking collection on you MondoDB. Also i want to point out that, if you are only interesting on the "user name", denormalization will optimaze you read operations.

Comment: When I don't use populate, my booking shows all the values correctly.  Jack Yu.

Comment: I think you have to  reset  DB, After removing all collections, and storing your data again, the relations managed by mongoose's populate() will work.

Answer (score 0):

Population does not occur unless a callback is passed or you explicitly call execPopulate(). Passing the same path a second time will overwrite the previous path options. See Model.populate() for explaination of options.

Code update: *populate("booker")***.exec();**

```
const booking = await Booking.findById(req.params.id).populate("booker").exec();
```

[More info here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-populate)